# SHOW COLUMNS alias in MySQL

Tags: mysql, bash, alias

I want to make an alias(as in bash) for the following MySQL query:

`SHOW COLUMNS FROM table WHERE Field != 'col_name' AND Field != 'col_name';`

I read something about *views* but it seems that I need a `SELECT` query to use them.

I want to type only something like: `showcols` in the MySQL prompt and in the background the above query to be executed, is that possible?

PS: I cannot use `DESCRIBE` because of the length of some enum fields in the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace the `show columns` with a `select` from the `information_schema` database.

```
SELECT column_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.`columns` 
WHERE column_name not IN ('col1','col2');
```

Now you can create a `view` based on this select:

```
CREATE VIEW as SELECT ......
```

Comment: Thanks. I created a longer query based on yours to imitate DESCRIBE, then created a view and it worked!